# We are seven minutes in. No score yet

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

While watching a football game,
"We are seven minutes in. No score yet."

What does "seven minutes in" mean?

And what does it mean by "in"?

Comment: Seven minutes into the game. The game (or part of it) has lasted for 7 minutes, but nobody has scored a goal yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Seven minutes **in**" means "seven minutes into the game". The game (or part of it) has lasted for 7 minutes, but nobody has scored a goal yet.

Comment: Specifically, 7 minutes (of the 32, 48, or 60 minutes) of playing time have elapsed.  More than 7 minutes of actual time (including time outs and other time when "the clock is stopped") may have elapsed.  (College and professional football games generally have four 15-minute quarters.  High school varsity games often have four 12-minute quarters, and games for younger athletes often have four 8-minute quarters.)